# Error trying to plot 2 images with different size using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, plot, surf

I have 2 images that I need to plot in one figure then display the points of interest found with SURF on both images:
 Image 1 : size  [6113x5693x3]
 Image 2 :  size  [4896x3744x3]
when trying to plot both of images in one figure  with this code:

```
I = zeros([size(I1,1) size(I1,2)*2 size(I1,3)]);
I(:,1:size(I1,2),:)=I1;
I(:,size(I1,2)+1:size(I1,2)+size(I2,2),:)=I2;
figure, imshow(I); hold on;
```

and to display the points of interest of each one of them with :

```
plot([Pos1(:,2) Pos2(:,2)+size(I1,2)]',[Pos1(:,1) Pos2(:,1)]','-');
plot([Pos1(:,2) Pos2(:,2)+size(I1,2)]',[Pos1(:,1) Pos2(:,1)]','o');
```

I get this error and I dont know how to fixed :

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

Any suggestion will be welcome!

Comment: Can you indicate the line where the error occurs ?

Answer (score 1):

Walk through this line by line. The error occurs on line 3. You are trying to assign I2 (with dimension 4896x3744x3) to a select part of I that has an incorrect first dimension (since the first dimension of I is the same as I1, not I2).

```
size(I(:,size(I1,2)+1:size(I1,2)+size(I2,2),:)) = [ 6113  3744  3 ]

size(I2) = [4896 3744  3]
```

Comment: This code is dedicated for images of the same size, I ask how can I modify it to display the two images of different size

Comment: So you want them side by side? Or on top of each other? The question does not suggest what exactly you are looking for